# merge 2 app with single app in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I already created PDF and CSV file now i have to merge both app in single app ,How to merge PDF and CSV file app with in single app...?

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        console.log('DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER', (Date.now() - before), 'ms');

        cordova.plugins.pdf.htmlToPDF({
                data: "<html> <h1>  Hello World  </h1> </html>",
                documentSize: "A4",
                landscape: "portrait",
                type: "share"
            },
            (sucess) => console.log('sucess: ', sucess),
            (error) => console.log('error:', error));
    });
```

Comment: you want to merge 2 apps? or 2 files?

Comment: i want to merge 2 app PDF and CSV